# How to ignore incompatible engine "node" error on installing npm dependencies with yarn?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

Given this `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "yarn-install-fail",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {},
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "2.x.x",
    "s3-streams": "^0.3.0"
  }
}
```

I can install the dependencies successfully via npm:

```
$ npm install

added 27 packages in 1.844s
```

Yet yarn fails:

```
$ yarn install
yarn install v0.24.5
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error s3-streams@0.3.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^1.2.0".
error Found incompatible module
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

It appears yarn has trouble installing the library `s3-streams@0.3.0`, yet I assumed it would fallback to install all the dependencies anyway like `npm` would.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

You can indeed ignore such errors via [--ignore-engines](https://github.com/gilbarbara/react-joyride/issues/131#issuecomment-253319816):

```
$ yarn install --ignore-engines
yarn install v0.24.5
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 1.41s.
```

This is also documented in the command's help:

```
$ yarn help | grep -- --ignore
    --ignore-scripts                  don't run lifecycle scripts
    --ignore-platform                 ignore platform checks
    --ignore-engines                  ignore engines check
    --ignore-optional                 ignore optional dependencies
```

Comment: Hello! Can I do such thing in npm?

Comment: Hi! How does it work with scripts like test, for example, yarn test --ignore-engines. Does it work? I don't think it works. That's why I'm asking. The problem I'm facing is I get that trouble when doing yarn test.

Comment: @sunsets Scripts are placeholder for any command. So without details to what you are trying to execute, it could be anything. I assume that your `test` script at one point executes a `yarn install` without `--ignore-engine`. Adding a flag to a script does not mean it will be passed down to all the other commands in that chain.

Comment: The error still shows up when you issue: 'yarn start' command

Comment: Then this answer in the same question will help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61102972/787399 (just remove the engine section from your package.json, if it exists).

Comment: yarn install --ignore-engines
worked for me, so thanks!

Answer (score 92):

`yarn config set ignore-engines true` is a one time fix for the "the engine node is incompatible with this module" problem. Once that is completed, you can do "create-react-app my-app"

Comment: We added it into the preinstall task: `"preinstall": "yarn config set ignore-engines true",` :)

Answer (score 10):

`--ignore-engines` doesn't work with the `yarn start` command

So there are two solutions for that to get rid of it.

check your node version with:

> node -v

check your npm version with:

> npm -v

Open package.json and make sure the values you got from running the two commands above match with the versions of `node` and `npm` in the `engines` object.

OR

You can simply remove `engines` from the package.json file otherwise it will always check the version to match.

Comment: Removing the `engines` field from `package.json` works for me while running `yarn run start`. My problem was due to the version of `node and npm` on my local system is different from the one on the server on digitalOcean.

Answer (score 8):

add     `--ignore-engines` to remove the errors

```
 $ yarn help 
....
    --ignore-scripts                  don't run lifecycle scripts
    --ignore-platform                 ignore platform checks
    --ignore-engines                  ignore engines check
    --ignore-optional                 ignore optional dependencies
....
```

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest way I found for doing this is to create a file called `.yarnrc` right next to your `package.json` file, with the following content:

```
ignore-engines true
```

This ties the setting to your project only (no global changes needed) and it also gets committed into your repo. It also allows you to remove the setting in the future, when it's not going to be needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you run into this problem, it might be because
you have several versions of `node` on your system.

For example, you might have run some command that installs an uptodate
version of node in one place, but be running a different version of
node because it's directory is ahead of the other one in $PATH.

So it might be a good idea to run

`which -a node`

If the nvm version is out-of-date, you could update it, e.g.
to a particular version: `nvm install 15.4.0`