# How to fix: "error fsevents@2.0.7: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module."

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, yarnpkg, mern

I want to deploy my website to Heroku but I get the next error:

```
error fsevents@2.0.7: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
error Found incompatible module.
```

I've already tried upgrading yarn, node but it didn't help. I use macOS Mojave v 10.14.5 and I cannot understand why is linux here.

```
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  10.15.3
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        engines.yarn (package.json):  unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 10.15.3...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 10.15.3...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.4.1
remote:        Resolving yarn version 1.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing yarn (1.17.3)...
remote:        Installed yarn 1.17.3
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
remote:        yarn install v1.17.3
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        [2/4] Fetching packages...
error fsevents@2.0.7: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        error Found incompatible module.
```

Comment: i'm stuck in this same issue over a month and i give up, i literally tried everything possible and googled all the internet for a solution, nothing solves this. so i changed to yarn

Comment: see yarn issue [fsevents@1.1.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3726)

Answer (score 15):

`yarn --ignore-platform`
This will fix the issue. As the name suggests it'll ignore the platform(Mac/Linux) and install those dependencies.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should be used like so `yarn install --ignore-engines` (found the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45088032/5783745))

Comment: @stevec  `yarn` command works same as `yarn install` command. So  `yarn --ignore-platform` is same as `yarn install --ignore-engines`

Answer (score 11):

I removed lines

```
fsevents@^1.2.7, fsevents@^2.0.6:
  version "2.0.7"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/fsevents/-/fsevents-2.0.7.tgz#382c9b443c6cbac4c57187cdda23aa3bf1ccfc2a"
  integrity sha512-a7YT0SV3RB+DjYcppwVDLtn13UQnmg0SWZS7ezZD0UjnLwXmy8Zm21GMVGLaFGimIqcvyMQaOJBrop8MyOp1kQ==
```

and

```
  optionalDependencies:
    fsevents "^2.0.6"
```

from `yarn.lock`. Next I removed

```
    "fsevents": "2.0.7",
```

from `resolutions` key in `package.json`

Finally on `yarn install` I can see

```
info fsevents@2.0.7: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.0.7" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
```

and

```
success Saved lockfile.
```

---

You do not need this module because of this is only for MacOS

> Native access to MacOS FSEvents in Node.js

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents

Comment: Is it recommended to edit yarn.lock by hand?

Comment: I think it is not recommended, but fsevents should be optional dependency because is needed only on mac. Probably there is bug in package dependencies list or in yarn.

Comment: you'd have to do this after each `yarn install`

Answer (score 3):

I'm getting the error now, but Heroku excludes fsevents and results in a successful deploy.

```
info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
remote:        info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
```

`https://my-app.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku`.

I didn't modify `yarn.lock` or any other files. I ended up at the post because I was curious about the error and now I know it's for macOS only. In other words ignore the error and leave `yarn.lock` alone.

Comment: Just a heads up that this advice this may work for heroku, but probably won't for other services. It is still a fatal error in many situations and removing it or somehow making it conditional for macos or local development only (perhaps turning it into a devDependency, which you use locally, and when you build elsewhere on linux, you'd use a $NODE_ENV of production?) is still the correct fix, in my not so humble opinion :)

Comment: That's odd, I experience the opposite: no problems locally (macOS), but have the problem on heroku.

Comment: @stevec same. any solution?

Comment: @RoniLitman tbh, I can't recall what eventually solved it. But, I searched my activity around the same time as the above comment and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75501288/5783745), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75500818/5783745) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75500491/5783745), hopefully something there may be useful.